# kivy ToggleButton dispatch does not toggle

Tags: kivy

Let's say I have a ToggleButton with an id 'btn_toggle'. If I do this from code:

```
self.ids['btn_toggle'].dispatch('on_press')
```

then the on_press event is fired, and the bound event handlers are called. Everything is fine, except that the button is not toggled at all. The toggle button group is not updated. Is this a bug, or should I use a different event for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on_press` event and the `state` property of the button are less linked than you think, in fact, they can change/be triggered pretty much independently.

If you want to change the state of the button, you just do that `self.ids.btn_toggle.state = 'down'`, but it won't automatically create an `on_press` event (that is directly triggered by the click), so if that's what you want, you still need to do it.

Basically, in a `ToggleButton`, `on_press` means that the user clicked the button, if the button was already down, it won't change its state, until the user releases the touch (and then you get an `on_release` event, as well as an `on_state` event), if the button was not down, you get both an `on_press` and an `on_state` event, and you get an `on_release` event (only) when the user releases the touch.

It might be that you actually want to react to `on_state` instead of `on_press`, if what interests you is the state of the button, not of the touch on the button.

Comment: File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 713, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy\_event.c:8133): KeyError: 'on_state' - I understand that it is enough to set the state property, but it seems strange that the on_state is a special event that cannot be dispatched manually.

Comment: Well, i assume it could be misleading to dispatch property events with values different from the state of the property, so it's better only to dispatch automatically via value change.